# How to toggle enable/disable input field based on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of radio buttons with the lase option "Other" and an input `field type text`. By default the input field is disabled, if you click on "Other" radio button the field is then enabled. How do I disable the input field if the select on radio button is changed?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true)
 });
$("#lastt").click(function(){ $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', false/true)});
```

this code is not disabling the input field if you change the radio select.

**UPDATE 1**
I'm trying this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true);
 });
$("#lastt").click(function(){ 
if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#text-inputt").prop("disabled", false);
  }  else {
      $("#text-inputt").prop("disabled", true);
  }  
});
```

But is not setting the input to disable if you change the radio button.

Comment: use attr instead of prop

Comment: please post your html..

Comment: Because you have to listen for a `change` event on all the radio buttons. Not only a `click` on a single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/uxb8kw2x/4/)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        if($(this).prop('id') == "lastt"){
         $("#text-inputt").prop("disabled", false);
      }else{
        $("#text-inputt").prop("disabled", true);
      }

    });
 });
```

Comment: It has to be radio

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true)
});
$("#lastt").click(function(){ $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', false/true)});
```

to

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true)
 });
 $("#lastt").click(function(){
 if($(this).val=='Other')
 {
 $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', false)
 }
 else
 {
  $("#text-inputt").prop('disabled', true)
 }
 });
```

Comment: I need to use `.is(':checked')` because I don't have a value to that radio button

Comment: replace if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
with  if($(this).is(':checked')=='true') {

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Here Input box will toggle ie Enable/Disbale

```
$("#radioBtn").change(function(){
  $("#inputBox").attr("disabled", ! $(this).is(':checked'));    
});
```

Comment: The function is only triggered when you select it

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:

- add a `change` listener to your radio button group
- When a radio changes, check its value
- if the value is 'other', enable the input field.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/3afjqe7j/1/

```
var $input = $('#text-inputt');

$("input[name=my-radios]").on('change', function() {
    var disabled = $(this).val() !== 'other';
    $input.prop('disabled', disabled);
});
```